# Cannot understand the Typescript syntax

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to `Typescript` and need help in understanding some code.

code :

```
addSilentCallBackHandler(): void {
  this.mgr.signinSilentCallback().then(callback());    
}

function callback(): (value: any) => void | PromiseLike<void> {
  return (data: any) => {
    console.debug("callback");
  };
}
```

this.mgr.signinSilentCallback() calls the 'then' function. I want to pass the callback function as an arugment in the addSilentCallBackHandler method. However I am confused about the syntax. The return type seems to a function which again returns a fucntion ?? Can anyone please explain the callback function.

The mgr btw is the 'UserManager' which is in the OidcClient, which used for jwt token handling.

Comment: signinSilentCallback() - must return promise. After u get resolve executed promise u will execute "callback()" function who's will debug message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `callback` function returns a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types). It will return a function (of type `(value:any) => void`) OR a `PromiseLike<void>` object. From the implementation we see, that it actually returns a function. This function is passed to `then` and will be called once the Promise that is returned from `signinSilentCallback()` was resolved.

What will happen is: `signinSilentCallback()` returns a Promise and executes some task asynchronously, probably it performs some http requests. We tell the Promise to execute the result of `callback()` once it is resolved. When the async process finished, the Promise gets resolved and `console.debug("callback")` will be executed.

To make the example more complete, we could add another return path to `callback()` that actually returns a `PromiseLike`:

```
function callback(): ((value: any) => void) | PromiseLike<void> {
    // It can return both:
    if (/*...*/) {
        // a ((value: any) => void)
        return (data: any) => {
            console.debug("callback");
        };
    } else {
        // or a PromiseLike<void>
        return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
            console.debug("callback 2");
            resolve();
        });
    }
}
```

If you don't have the need to make this distinction, it's probably much easier to directly pass a function as callback, without creating it in another function.

```
addSilentCallBackHandler(): void {
   this.mgr.signinSilentCallback().then(callback);
}

function callback() {
   console.log('callback');
}
```

Comment: Ok and how do I take callback function as the argument for the addSilentCallBackHandler function?

Comment: @humbleCoder You can take the same type that is used by `then` which is like `addSilentCallBackHandler(cb: ((value: any) => void) | PromiseLike<void>)`

Answer (score 2):

`mgr.signinSilentCallback().then` is a future which sets the on complete handler (which is function - with some parameter value).

You probably want to add the callback handler like so `this.mgr.signinSilentCallback().then(callback)` in that way you are passing in the function (reference). Because if you just call it like this `this.mgr.signinSilentCallback().then(callback())` then you are passing in the result of the function (which is of type `Promise`).

And your callback should probably not return a further function, and it should just handle the response from the `Promise`.

```
addSilentCallBackHandler(): void {
      this.mgr.signinSilentCallback().then(callback);    
  }

callback(value: any): void {
    console.debug("callback");
}
```